# React Native Picker Confirm Button

Tags: react-native

I am asking here because I have researched this problem and cannot seem to find a solution. I am using the React Native Picker but by default this picker does not come with a 'Confirm' button at the top right for the user to press when they have selected an item. I am very new to React Native and mobile development so I apologise if this is a simple question but I am quite stuck. Does anyone know of a solution to implement this button?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Picker, View, Text } from 'react-native';

class ProposalPicker extends Component {
    state={proposal: ''}
    updateProposal = (proposal) => {
        this.setState({ proposal: proposal })
    }
    render() {
        return (

                <Picker selectedValue = {this.state.proposal} 
                        onValueChange = {this.updateProposal}
                        itemStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'grey' }}

                >

                    <Picker.Item label = "Test" value = "TestValue" />
                    <Picker.Item label = "Test" value = "TestValue" />
                    <Picker.Item label = "Test" value = "TestValue" />
                    <Picker.Item label = "Test" value = "TestValue" />
                    <Picker.Item label = "Test" value = "TestValue" />
                    <Picker.Item label = "Test" value = "TestValue" />
                    <Picker.Item label = "Test" value = "TestValue" />
                    <Picker.Item label = "Test" value = "TestValue" />

                </Picker>
                //<Text>{this.state.proposal}</Text>

        )
    }
}

const styles = {
    proposalPickerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'lightgrey'
    }
}

export default ProposalPicker;
```

Answer (score 2):

add a new function

```
handleConfirmClick(){
 //perform confirm action
}
```

and then add a new button underneath your picker

```
<button onClick={this.handleConfirmClick.bind(this)} >Confirm</button>
```

EDIT just noticed youre using ES(6?)

```
handleConfirmClick = () => {
//perform action 
}
```

EDIT 2 Unless you want this component to have a life cycle of its own, it may be best to place the `Picker`, confirm `Button` and your `onChangeHandler` in the parent component instead